# How to access a XML attribute name using Freemarker

Tags: xml, attributes, freemarker

I m new to Freemarker and due to time constraints I need some immediate help. I need to read the attribute names and its value , structure them and the result needs to be like below.

This is my XML
'''

```
<?xml  version="1.0"?>
<root>
<INV store="1" provider="123876"  ST702=".00" ST703=".00" ST704=".00" ST705=".00"/>
</root>
```

'''
I can access the attributes inside the element by writing this
'''
${root["INV/@store"]},${root["INV/@provider"]},${root["INV/@ST702"]},${root["INV/@ST703"]}......
'''
This gives the below results
'''

```
 2,123876,.00,.00,.00
```

'''

However , I need the result to be

```
2,123876,ST702,.00 

2,123876,ST703,.00 

2,123876,ST704,.00 

2,123876,ST705,.00
```

Will be looking forward for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the extract rule is above, but something like this:

```
<#assign inv=root.INV>
<#list inv.@@ as attr>
  <#if attr?node_name?starts_with('ST7')>
    ${inv.@store},${inv.@provider},${attr?node_name},${attr}<#lt>
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Also note that things like `${root["INV/@store"]}` can be written as `${root.INV.@store}`.

Comment: The ST702 and ST703 etc are all names of stores and their corresponding values are the quantity. .i.e why I need the name to appear in my txt. Anyways, your answer gave me exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :). I have a question though, why <#lt> ? is it to deal with space or something ?

Comment: `#lt` is to remove the indentation.